# Output private string child

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I don't know how is correct way to output private string child. For example if I want to output "name" in **private**, compiler show me error: *inaccessible due its protection level*. Proper way is to use **public** "Name" instead of private "name"? Because I want to access it via private and don't know how to fix the error.

```
class Person
        {
            private string name, lastname;
            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
                set { name = value; }
            }

            public string Lastname
            {
                get { return lastname; }
                set { lastname = value; }

            }
        }

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person1 = new Person("Matt", "Houdson");

Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", person1.name);


  //is inaccessible due its protection level
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` property (with a capital 'N') is configured as a publicly-accessible "getter" for the *private* `name` property, so you should access the person's name by using `Name` (with a capital 'N'):

`Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", person1.Name);`

Comment: But is this the proper way? This means I can't acces Public string via Private string?

Comment: Yes, it is very standard to create publicly-accessible properties with "getter" and "setter" methods to allow controlled access to private properties. This is essentially the principle behind encapsulation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

Comment: Is possible to acess Public "Name" via private "name"?

Comment: No, the private `name` holds no reference to the public `Name`, so while you can access `name` from `Name`, the inverse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two syntax errors in your Program. 
 1). You forgot about case-sensitivity ,

```
 `Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", person1.name);`
```

the `person1.name` Should be replaced by `person1.Name`. (`person1.name` is private)

2). You forgot to explicitly define the two arguments constructor in the `class Person` . Well I have re-written the code for you Below, please have a look:

```
class Person
    {

        private string name, lastname;

       public Person(string N, string LN)
        {
            name = N;
            lastname = LN;

        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Lastname
        {
            get { return lastname; }
            set { lastname = value; }

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person1 = new Person("Matt", "Houdson");

            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", person1.Name);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment but I don't have the reputation to add comments yet.

Just wanted to let you know that Slasher is right. If what your trying to do is stop people from changing the persons name after person1 has been constructed just remove the setters from your Properties and all's good.

Danny